# How can I copy a file from fix source path to destination with a wildcard C:\temp\2021*

Tags: windows

I want to copy a file from fix source to variable destination path using windows batch command as below:
Source file : C:\temp\test.txt
Destination path: C:\temp\2021*
Destination folder path can be anything like this 20210510182538
Please help me how can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

For /D %%G In ("C:\temp\*") DO copy /Y C:\temp\test.txt %%G